# Unable to locate package pkgconfig

Tags: installation, 12.10, kubuntu, software-sources

I try to install Ruby on Ubuntu 12. There is one of the commands which gives me an error

E: Unable to locate package pkgconfig

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential openssl libreadline6 libreadline6-dev curl git-core zlib1g zlib1g-dev libssl-dev libyaml-dev libsqlite3-dev sqlite3 libxml2-dev libxslt-dev autoconf libc6-dev ncurses-dev automake libtool bison subversion pkgconfig
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Note, selecting 'libxslt1-dev' instead of 'libxslt-dev'
Note, selecting 'libncurses5-dev' instead of 'ncurses-dev'
E: Unable to locate package pkgconfig
```

I even did

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install pkgconfig
```

but it didn't help.

How do I install pkgconfig?

If it helps you somehow

```
alex@ubuntu:~$ cat /etc/apt/sources.list
# deb cdrom:[Kubuntu 12.10 _Quantal Quetzal_ - Release amd64 (20121017.1)]/ quantal main multiverse restricted universe

# See http://help.ubuntu.com/community/UpgradeNotes for how to upgrade to
# newer versions of the distribution.
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu quantal main restricted
deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu quantal main restricted

## Major bug fix updates produced after the final release of the
## distribution.
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu quantal-updates main restricted
deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu quantal-updates main restricted

## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu
## team. Also, please note that software in universe WILL NOT receive any
## review or updates from the Ubuntu security team.
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu quantal universe
deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu quantal universe
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu quantal-updates universe
deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu quantal-updates universe

## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu 
## team, and may not be under a free licence. Please satisfy yourself as to 
## your rights to use the software. Also, please note that software in 
## multiverse WILL NOT receive any review or updates from the Ubuntu
## security team.
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu quantal multiverse
deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu quantal multiverse
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu quantal-updates multiverse
deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu quantal-updates multiverse

## N.B. software from this repository may not have been tested as
## extensively as that contained in the main release, although it includes
## newer versions of some applications which may provide useful features.
## Also, please note that software in backports WILL NOT receive any review
## or updates from the Ubuntu security team.
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu quantal-backports main restricted universe multiverse
deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu quantal-backports main restricted universe multiverse

deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu quantal-security main restricted
deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu quantal-security main restricted
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu quantal-security universe
deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu quantal-security universe
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu quantal-security multiverse
deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu quantal-security multiverse

## Uncomment the following two lines to add software from Canonical's
## 'partner' repository.
## This software is not part of Ubuntu, but is offered by Canonical and the
## respective vendors as a service to Ubuntu users.
# deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu quantal partner
# deb-src http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu quantal partner

## Uncomment the following two lines to add software from Ubuntu's
## 'extras' repository.
## This software is not part of Ubuntu, but is offered by third-party
## developers who want to ship their latest software.
# deb http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu quantal main
# deb-src http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu quantal main
```

Answer (score 39, accepted):

I think you are looking for `pkg-config` (with the dash), see `dpkg -l | grep pkg-config`.

Comment: it returns nothing

Comment: Which Ubuntu are you using? It should be in  there from 12.04 (http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=pkg-config)

Comment: Sorry I had to install `pkg-config` first. Its working fine now.